# mySQL query that Sorts by hierarchy while using foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sorting, select, hierarchy

Here is my table:

```
course
------
courseId
department
number
section
title
```

I want to do a query where it will sort them hierarchically. In this order:

1. department
2. number
3. section

So when I call this query...

```
SELECT * from `course` SORT BY ???
```

How do I sort by more than one column? What do I replace `???` with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just list them in order, separated by commas. Also, the keyword is `ORDER BY`, not `SORT BY`:

```
ORDER BY Department, Number, Section
```